# Whitespace at the top inside iframe?

Tags: html, css

```
Iframe {margin:none;padding:none;}
//inside the content there is 2 column separated into div

#left{margin-left 80px}
#right {marigin-right 50px}
```

But it seems like there is a blank space at the top of my content, any help?

Comment: is there an element that could be pushing a margin/padding at the top inside the iframe? Could you provide a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `Display:block` can help..If not provide a fiddle then it will be very helpful in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set this on the actual iframe too:

```
<iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" />
```

Otherwise, the content in your iFrame is causing it, it's most likely the `body { margin-top:0; }` for the content in the iFrame that needs to be set.